# Tower property of conditional expectation - simple proof.

Tags: probability

I have a bunch of properties of conditional expectation to prove. It seems that most proofs that I was able to find on the internet involved too much technical details for me, such as measurability and sigma algebras. I am looking for simpler proofs, are there any?

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be random variables.

Show that $\text{E}[\text{E}[Z|X,Y]|X] = \text{E}[Z|X]$

Let us start with the discrete case:
 We write $\text{E}[Z|X,Y] = h(X,Y)$ and so we get that 
$\text{E}[h(X,Y)|X] = \text{E}[h(X,Y)|X = x] = \text{E}[h(x,Y)]$ I am not sure if the last part is correct or if it requires independence of $X$ and $Y$. If it is correct,what does it mean? we had that $h(X,Y) =\text{E}[Z|X,Y]$, so what does $h(x,Y)$ mean? How do we continue form here?

Comment: What is your definition of conditional expectation?

Comment: $\operatorname{E} (X | Y=y ) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} x \ \operatorname{P}(X=x|Y=y) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} x \ \frac{\operatorname{P}(X=x,Y=y)}{\operatorname{P}(Y=y)}$

Comment: And what's your definition of the conditional expectation given a random variables, e.g. $E[Z\mid X]$?

Comment: As far as I know those two are the same, i.e. $\text{E}[Z|X=x] = \text{E}[Z|X]$..

Comment: No, $E[Z\mid X=x]$ is a number, while $E[Z\mid X]$ is a random variable.

Comment: True, of course. My teacher has not given any definition of $\text{E}[Z|X]$ but I reckon that, at least in the discrete case, you could just calculate $\text{E}[Z|X=x]$ for all possible values of $x$?